# sum of values in a python list of dictionaries

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary

This is my list of dictionaries:

```
[{'week': '23', 'total_entry': 1}, {'week': '23', 'total_entry': 4}, {'week': '24', 'total_entry': 2}]
```

I want to sum the total_entry values which are added in the same week, so what I want to get is this:

```
[{'week': '23', 'total_entry': 5}, {'week': '24', 'total_entry': 2}]
```

I can get a close result by writing some code but there must be a very easy way to get this result, I suppose. Can somebody have a look at it?

Comment: And what exactly is your approach to get this "close result"? What does close mean in this context? That you get an error message? Not the expected output?

Comment: Consider using named tuples instead of dicts. I have the impression that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I was able to get this defaultdict(int, {'23': 5, '24': 2}) it was actually ok for me but I needed a better dictionary. Anyway, solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) of python [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)  to group the elements in the list based on the key.

```
import itertools

input_list = [{'week': '23', 'total_entry': 1}, {'week': '23', 'total_entry': 4}, {'week': '24', 'total_entry': 2}]

new_list = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(input_list, lambda item: item["week"]):
    new_dict = {}
    new_dict['week'] = key
    new_dict['total_entry'] = sum([item["total_entry"] for item in group])
    new_list.append(new_dict)

print(new_list)
```

Output:-

```
[{'week': '23', 'total_entry': 5}, {'week': '24', 'total_entry': 2}]
```

Comment: Note this solution will only work if your `input_list` is sorted by `week` beforehand. If sorting is required, it's possible to use `itertools.groupby`, but complexity will increase to O(n log n).

Answer (score 2):

Using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

L = [{'week': '23', 'total_entry': 1}, {'week': '23', 'total_entry': 4},
     {'week': '24', 'total_entry': 2}]

d = defaultdict(int)

for item in L:
    d[item['week']] += item['total_entry']

print(d)

defaultdict(int, {'23': 5, '24': 2})
```

Then using a dictionary comprehension for your desired format:

```
res = [{'week': k, 'total_entry': v} for k, v in d.items()]

print(res)

[{'week': '23', 'total_entry': 5}, {'week': '24', 'total_entry': 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [{'week': '23', 'total_entry': 1}, {'week': '23', 'total_entry': 4}, {'week': '24', 'total_entry': 2}]

from collections import defaultdict
j = defaultdict(int)
for i in a:
    j[i['week']] += i['total_entry']
print(j)
```